# error handing for uploading large size file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can a send message to user if file uploaded exceeds the maximum limit on server side using asp.net.
 I have wriiten following code in global.asax

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Dim ex As New Exception
    ex = Server.GetLastError()
    If TypeOf ex Is HttpUnhandledException AndAlso ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
        ex = ex.InnerException
    End If
    If (ex IsNot Nothing) And ex.Message.Contains("Maximum request length exceeded") Then

         Server.ClearError()

        Server.Transfer("/Errors.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

It does not display erros page instead get Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Answer (score 0):

That's too late in the cycle. Test for it in Application_BeginRequest like this:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim runtime As HttpRuntimeSection = CType(WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpRuntime"), HttpRuntimeSection)
    ' Approx 100 Kb(for page content) size has been deducted because the maxRequestLength proprty 
    ' is the page size, not only the file upload size
    Dim maxRequestLength As Integer = (runtime.MaxRequestLength - 100) * 1024
    ' This code is used to check the request length of the page and if the request length is 
    ' greater than MaxRequestLength then return to the same page with extra query string value action=exception
    Dim myContext As HttpContext = CType(sender, HttpApplication).Context

    If myContext.Request.ContentLength > maxRequestLength Then

        ' We need to consume the file otherwise the browser will detect that the upload did not complete 
        ' and assume that the connection was broken and display a "page not found" error
        Dim pro As IServiceProvider = CType(myContext, IServiceProvider)
        Dim workerRequest As HttpWorkerRequest = DirectCast(pro.GetService(GetType(HttpWorkerRequest)), HttpWorkerRequest)
        If workerRequest.HasEntityBody Then
            Dim requestLength As Integer = workerRequest.GetTotalEntityBodyLength
            Dim initialBytes As Integer = 0
            If workerRequest.GetPreloadedEntityBody IsNot Nothing Then
                initialBytes = workerRequest.GetPreloadedEntityBody.Length
            End If
            If Not workerRequest.IsEntireEntityBodyIsPreloaded Then
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(511999) {}
                Dim receivedBytes As Integer = initialBytes
                While (requestLength - receivedBytes) >= initialBytes
                    initialBytes = workerRequest.ReadEntityBody(buffer, buffer.Length)
                    receivedBytes += initialBytes
                End While
                initialBytes = workerRequest.ReadEntityBody(buffer, requestLength - receivedBytes)
            End If

            Response.Redirect("~/Utility/ErrorMaxLength.htm")
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Source http://weblogs.asp.net/hosamkamel/resolving-maximum-request-length-exceeded-exception